# I can't find holtwinters in statsmodels in python

Tags: python, importerror

I can't find holtwinters in statsmodels in Python & got this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-73a8092b756a> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters'
```

Comment: Do you have statsmodels installed..? ```pip install statsmodels```

Comment: yes i did, but for this particular module i got that message

Comment: Update the statsmodel library and restart the kernel? That would be my guess.

Comment: pip install statsmodels? or other command?

Comment: ```pip install --upgrade statsmodels```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine